# I can't upload files larger than 45 KB using wcf

Tags: wcf

My code works perfect for files smaller than 45 Kb but when I upload files large files I get that error:

> The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
>
> Source Error:
>
> ```
> Line 120:        [System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableAttribute(System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)]
> Line 121:        WebApplication2.ServiceReference1.uploadfileResponse WebApplication2.ServiceReference1.IService1.uploadfile(WebApplication2.ServiceReference1.RemoteFileInfo request) {
> Line 122:            return base.Channel.uploadfile(request);
> Line 123:        }
> Line 124:
> ```
>
> Source File: `C:\Users\KHALED\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\WcfServicefiles\WebApplication2\Service References\ServiceReference1\Reference.cs`
>   Line: 122
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> ```
> [WebException: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.]
>    System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse() +6115427
>    System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout) +48
>
> [ProtocolException: The remote server returned an unexpected response: (400) Bad Request.]
>    System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg) +9455983
>    System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type) +345
>    WebApplication2.ServiceReference1.IService1.uploadfile(RemoteFileInfo request) +0
>    WebApplication2.ServiceReference1.Service1Client.WebApplication2.ServiceReference1.IService1.uploadfile(RemoteFileInfo request) in C:\Users\KHALED\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\WcfServicefiles\WebApplication2\Service References\ServiceReference1\Reference.cs:122
>   WebApplication2._Default.Button2_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\KHALED\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\WcfServicefiles\WebApplication2\Default.aspx.cs:38
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +118
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +112
> System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +10
>   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +13
>   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +36
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +5563
> ```

This is my webconfig code for the server:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
     <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2097151"
    useFullyQualifiedRedirectUrl="true"
               executionTimeout="14400"

                 />
  </system.web>

  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="SomeServiceServiceBehavior">
          <!--   To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="6553600"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->

        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="Service1"
        maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
        maxBufferSize="2147483647" transferMode="Streamed">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
        maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"
        maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"/>
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Ntlm"/>
          </security>
        </binding>            
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service name="Service1.svc.cs"  >
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding"
                  bindingConfiguration="Service1"
                  contract="IService1" >

        </endpoint>



      </service>

    </services>


    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
 <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>

  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

And this the web.config for the client

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->

<configuration>
  <configSections>
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ApplicationServices"
         connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
      <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2097150"      />

    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>

    <membership>
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices"
             enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false"
             maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10"
             applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </membership>

    <profile>
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/"/>
      </providers>
    </profile>

    <roleManager enabled="false">
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/" />
        <add name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>

  </system.web>

  <system.webServer>
     <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>

        <behavior  name="SomeServiceServiceBehavior">
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="6553600"/>

        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior  name="SomeServiceServiceBehavior">
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="6553600"/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" closeTimeout="04:01:00"
          openTimeout="04:01:00" receiveTimeout="04:10:00" sendTimeout="04:01:00"
          allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
          maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
          messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Streamed"
          useDefaultWebProxy="true">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="128" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647"
            maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
              realm="" />
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
     <endpoint address="http://localhost/WcfServicefiles/Service1.svc"
        binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService1"
        contract="ServiceReference1.IService1" name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below section of your servers web.config

```
  <services>
      <service name="Service1.svc.cs"  >
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding"
                  bindingConfiguration="Service1"
                  contract="IService1" >
        </endpoint>
      </service>
    </services>
```

has some values for attributes that are wrong.  The value for the name attribute of service element needs to be namespace.Service1 and similarly the contract attribute value of endpoint element needs to be namespace.IService1 as shown below:

```
  <services>
      <service name="<namespace>.Service1"  >
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding"
                  bindingConfiguration="Service1"
                  contract="<namespace>.IService1" >
        </endpoint>
      </service>
    </services>
```

Just replace  with the namespace of Service1 class. And that should work

Answer (score 0):

Try follwing this example: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/166763/WCF-Streaming-Upload-Download-Files-Over-HTTP